# Why do I get an error while building a test package from "Fixing a bug in Ubuntu"?

Tags: 12.04, development

I am trying to make my first bug fixing for Ubuntu.
While following the *fixing a bug* instruction from [fixing-a-bug](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug.html) and 
[packaging: link via changelog](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/udd-working.html#link-via-changelog) on developer.ubuntu.com I have encountered a problem at the setup "Testing the fix".

While trying to build with `bzr builddeb -- -S -us -uc`, I have encountered below error message:

```
dpkg-source: info: using source format `3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building totem using existing ./totem_3.0.1.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: error: cannot read totem-3.0.1.orig.B4x9vh/debian/patches/totem-1041032-fixed: No such file or directory
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b totem-3.0.1 gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1350:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -d -us -uc -S failed
bzr: ERROR: The build failed.
```

It seems there's no such folder `totem-3.0.1.orig.B4x9vh`.

I was stuck on not knowing why and how these folder would be generated under my Branching for a change.

Comment: Could you update your question with the entire output from your attempt to build this package please? My guess is that a file that was generated and intended to go in one place has ended up in another somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue in other way and build the package in my environment.

Basically follow the steps given at [packaging:link-via-changelog](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/udd-working.html#link-via-changelog)

Firstly, download the source code and create another branch. Run these commands:

```
cd tomboy.dev
bzr pull
bzr branch tomboy.dev bug-12345
```

And then before making any changes, I need to go back to the source package and create an `*.orig.tar.gz` source package.

Simply change the directory to `tomboy.dev` and run `bzr bd -- -S -us -uc`.

Then I could start modifying my changes in bug-12345. After modifying, I used `dch -i` and `debcommit` to commit the changes.

And then instead of using `bzr` command to generate the package, I used `debuild/dpkg-buildpackage` instead.

For generating pure source code package: I use `debuild -S`

And to generate a release binary build: I use `dpkg-buildpackage`.

---

Reference: [dpkg-buildpakcage](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html)